# Seaborn Grouped Violin Plot WITHOUT pandas

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

For reasons I won't get into I need to make violin plots without using a pandas dataframe. For example I have the following ndarray and categories.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.random.randn(5, 3)
category = np.array(["yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes","yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"])

ax = sns.violinplot(data = data)
plt.show()
```

Results in an ungrouped violin plot.

[image: violin plots]

However, I'd like to use the categorical data to make a grouped violin plot

```
ax = sns.violinplot(data = data, x = category)
plt.show()
```

Gives an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'`. Is there any way around this without pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not use the `data` parameter if using multiple numpy arrays for `x`, `y` and `hue`.
2. From `y`, you can create an array of indices with `np.nonzero`.
3. Make sure all of your `np.arrays` are one-dimensional with `.flatten()`. For example I `flatten` your array of random floats from a shape of `5,3` to `15,1`; Otherwise, you will get an error since the arrays have different shapes and `Seaborn` doesn't have a way to figure it out as it can with a `pandas` dataframe.

Likewise, if you pass three `(5,3)` arrays to `x`, `y` and `hue`, then Seaborn won't know what to do. So, you must either a) `FLATTEN` all arrays and make them equal length of `(15,0)` OR b) use a pandas dataframe.

---

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y = np.random.randn(5, 3)
x = np.nonzero(y)[-1]
y = y.flatten()
hue = np.array(["yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes","yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"])
sns.violinplot(x=x, y=y, hue=hue)
```

[image]

```
print(x,'\n\n',y,'\n\n',hue)

[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2] 

 [-0.28618123 -1.18132595  0.70535902  0.90685532 -1.27258432  0.90417094
  3.03506025  0.99796779  0.20247628  0.43226169  0.25005372 -0.9923336
 -0.43102785 -0.17117549 -0.16147393] 

 ['yes' 'no' 'no' 'no' 'yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'no' 'yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'no' 'no'
 'no' 'no']
```

Comment: Thanks @David Erickson. This is exactly what I needed.